# /usr/bin/env: 'ruby': No such file or directory when deploy ruby on rails app on heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

I am trying to deploy my app on heroku. Build succeeded, but when I run

```
heroku run rake db:migrate
```

I get

```
/usr/bin/env: 'ruby': No such file or directory
```

How to fix that?

All the other stuff work nice, command like bundle install and so on.
Command

```
which ruby
```

returns `/Users/lbrezgin/.rbenv/shims/ruby`

Comment: Would you mind elaborating on what your application looks like? What version of Ruby and Ruby on Rails do you use? Did you double-check that the `heroku/ruby` buildpack is installed on your Heroku app (find this information in the Settings tab)? Would you mind sharing the exact command and output in the CLI when you try running those commands? Btw `which ruby` returns how it looks like on your local machine. But the `heroku run` prefix runs the command on Heroku.